# How to show image on submit

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to when user enters an img, show that img on web page. My code:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter an image URL." id="myinput">
<button onclick="myFunc()">Submit Image</button>

<script>
  function myFunc () {
    const inp = document.getElementById ('myinput')
    const img = document.createElement ('img')
    img.src = inp.value
    document.getElementById('body').appendChild(img)
  }
</script>
```

But it's not working and the code just adds an `?` to end of web page URL (myweb.com/image?). How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to get the body, instead you can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) with selector as  `'body'` or assign `id` to your body tag:

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter an image URL." value="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg?v=e5e58ae7df45" id="myinput">
  <button onclick="myFunc()">Submit Image</button>

  <script>
    function myFunc() {
      const inp = document.getElementById('myinput');
      const img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = inp.value;
      document.querySelector('body').appendChild(img);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting you src attribute using setAttribute method and body is itself a dom element you dont need to use querySelector for body.

Try this:

```
img.setAttribute("src", inp.value);
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter an image URL."id="myinput">
<button onclick="myFunc()">Submit Image</button>
<img id="image-display" class="width:100px; height:100px"></img>

<script>
    function myFunc() {
        const inp = document.getElementById('myinput').value;
        document.getElementById('image-display').setAttribute("src",inp);
    }
</script>
</body>
```

You can avoid creating elements inside the function. To your problem of not selecting the element, you are trying to access an element () using an ID. You should have assigned an ID or use [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Read more about [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) interface.